# What is the windows "wmic os get serialnumber" command

Tags: operating-system, wmic, serial-number

I have a question

Is the output of the cmd code `wmic os get serialnumber` that prints the operating system's serialnumber "unique & persistent" ?

I mean by [unique]: is it different on two PCs even if i install A copy of windows from the same DVD on both PCs ?

And I mean by [persistent]: is it will stay the same on all local users that use the PC and never changed ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the serial number is created from a hash with information from the windows media + hardware information making it unique per machine